# ¿Como validar inputs con framework7 y vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, framework7

Sucede que tengo el siguiente input de un formulario, trabajando con framework7 y vuejs.

```
<f7-list-input
             outline
             label="Nombre"
             floating-label
             type="text"
             :value="usuario.nombre" 
             @input="usuario.nombre = $event.target.value"
             placeholder="Nombre"
             clear-button
             autocomplete="new-user"
             required
             validate
             error-message="Debe ingresar un nombre"
            >
            <f7-icon slot="media" icon="fas fa-user-alt" size="25px"></f7-icon>
        </f7-list-input>
```

Trabajando con la validación de la documentación.

Efectivamente al inicio se realiza bien la validación:
Ejemplo del input:
antes de validar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Input validando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ingresar un texto para que desaparezca que es obligatorio ingresar texto sucede lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desaparece la sombra en rojo, pero permanece el texto "Debe ingresar un nombre".

¿Que podrá ser el error? ya que al ingresar texto debe desaparecer el texto también.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren tres formas:

1. Al realizar el `@input`, llamar un método que si `usuario.nombre.length > 0`, resetee la validación.
2. Crear un `deep watch` a ese model que cada vez que se actualice el input, compruebe el length.
3. Hacer un `$ref` a ese input y comprobar el estado del mismo, algo así:

```html
<f7-list-input
    label="Name"
    type="text"
    :value="name"
    @blur="checkInputValidation($event.target.value)"
    placeholder="Your name"
    clear-button
    ref="input" 
    v-model="valid"
  ></f7-list-input>
```

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      valid: false,
    }),
    methods: {
      checkInputValidation: function(val) {
        if(val.length>0) this.$refs.input.reset()
      } 
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: una consulta el @input. ya me encuentro utilizando de la siguiente forma:  @input="usuario.usuario = $event.target.value", como se le agregaría lo otro checkInputValidation?

Comment: Entonces utilizalo en un `@blur`, para que cuando pierda el foco, haga la validación. He actualizado de acuerdo a tu uso.

Comment: en mi caso utilizo: this.$f7.input, y me imprime:
 `blur: ƒ ()
checkEmptyState: ƒ ()
focus: (...)
init: ƒ ()
resizeTextarea: ƒ ()
scrollIntoView: ƒ ()
validate: ƒ ()
validateInputs: ƒ ()
`
pero al hacer uso de .reset(), indique que no es una función y si utilizo this.$refs.input, aparece como undefined. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Mira esto: https://framework7.io/docs/inputs.html#validation

Comment: aun no he podido solucionarlo.